# InDesign CS5: How to create a contact sheet automatically?

Tags: adobe-indesign

I know the [instructions](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/indesign/cs/using/WSca1f2095bad2f36e1172e0811e280c9e3b-8000.html) exist. I have tried them repeatedly and they simply don't make sense. Can someone explain the steps a little better? (Reading down the list of comments, I'm not the only confused person. The last comment on the page was a second attempt at explaining the process, and I'm still not getting the cursor I should get.)

When I try to place several images at once, I get a loaded cursor icon, but all that ever happens is that I'm placing one image after another, in individual boxes, which is not what I want. How is it supposed to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah, welcome to Gridify! It's not the most transparent of features, but it is way cool for placing a bunch of images. Jing's not going to let me grab the screenshots I'd need, so I'll point you to [Michael Ninness' video](http://tv.adobe.com/watch/visual-design-cs5/grid-mode-and-live-distribute/) that demonstrates it beautifully.

The trick is, you press the arrow keys *while you are dragging out the first frame* to create the grid, but as you'll see in the video there's way more to gridify than just that. At the end he demos what might be (but isn't) called "spacify." It's also way cool.

Comment: WOW, wow wow wow. Thank you. That video FINALLY explained what I was looking for. Thank you! (See, if SE had a DM capability, I would have just asked you, because I knew you'd know. :) )

Comment: I know. It got me at first, too, just like Illustrator's "press the arrow keys to change the number of sides in a polygon" baffled me, back in the day. It's counter-intuitive, somehow, to be pressing keys while you're dragging with the mouse. o_O

Comment: It's counterintuitive to be pressing keys all the way over *there* while dragging with the mouse. I kept hitting keys closer to the left. The < and > ? the brackets? what's the "cursor" key?

Comment: The cursor key is the one that makes you curse when you have to use it with your left hand because your right hand is holding down a $@%^#$! mouse button, fer cryin' out loud.